# how to find the minimum number of ascending subsequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I meet a problem. http://poj.org/problem?id=1065
The problem is to find the minimum number of ascending subsequences.
I see somebody is to find the length of longest descending subsequences.
I don't know why the two numbers are equal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <memory.h>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;
pair<int,int> stick[5000];
int dp[5000];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>stick[i].first>>stick[i].second;
        }
    sort(stick,stick+n);
    memset(dp,-1,sizeof(int)*5000);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       *lower_bound(dp,dp+n,stick[i].second,greater<int>())=stick[i].second; 
        }
        cout<<lower_bound(dp, dp + n, -1, greater<int>()) - dp<<endl;

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't find the length of the longest descending subsequence. Those numbers aren't equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows immediately from the [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem). It's a standard technique for solving problems like this.